# http meta refresh issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, visual-studio-2008

I am using http meta refresh to reflesh current page to keep session live. I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 and developing ASP.Net application.

My question is, is it possible to send from client (browser) side If-Not-Modified-Since request header to server side and check if at server side responses 304 Not-Modified header to client? (I want to use this to optmize bandwidth and overhead at server.)

If yes, could anyone recommend me some sample code at client side and at server side how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially be addressed with the `HtmlMeta` class that was added in .NET 2.0.  It allows programmatic access to the meta keywords.  You can check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlmeta%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, the link is very helpful. Actually my question is not how to use Meta Control, but how to send from client (browser) side If-Not-Modified-Since request header to server side and check if at server side responses 304 Not-Modified header to client? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with ASP.NET, but in general, for something like this, consider using [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Comment: Thanks, two questions. 1. Does all major browsers support Etag? 2. For the logics -- "When a new HTTP response contains the same ETag as an older HTTP response, the contents are considered to be the same without further downloading.", do we need to implement it by ourselves or browser has built-in implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's Ajax api see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), there is a `ifModified` param. Moreover, the use of HTTP Meta Refresh is discouraged by W3C

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use META Refresh. If you want to reload the page, use the JavaScript method window.location.reload(false);

I explain why here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/meta-refresh-causes-additional-http-requests.aspx
and 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/07/08/technical-information-about-conditional-http-requests-and-the-refresh-button.aspx